# How python decorator works with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, decorator, python-decorators

I have the below code

```
def memo(fn):
    cache = {}
    miss = object()
    print 'MEMO'
    def wrapper(*args):
        result = cache.get(args, miss)
        print 'IT CALLS'
        if result is miss:
            print 'IT MISSES'
            result = fn(*args)
            cache[args] = result
        return result
    return wrapper

@memo
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

when I call fib(4) it prints MEMO only once. Following is the output.

```
MEMO
IT CALLS
IT MISSES
IT CALLS
IT MISSES
IT CALLS
IT MISSES
IT CALLS
IT MISSES
IT CALLS
IT MISSES
IT CALLS
IT CALLS
```

What is causing this behaviour ??

Comment: that might be non_relevant, but you might want to use linear computation of fib using tuple of (fib(n), fib(n-1)) as return value for your fib function.

Comment: You really want to read *all* of [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/100297).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour and has nothing to do with recursion.

MEMO is printed when the decorator is called, which happens *when it is applied to a function*; ie, at definition time. If you never called `fib()` at all, MEMO would still be printed.

Answer (score 2):

You only print `MEMO` when *applying* the decorator. It is not part of the `wrapper` function, which is what the decorator produces to replace the original function.